# Convert a property with AngularJS to a specific format??

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have the following data binding expression (property) in Angularjs:

`{{ data.cardNumber }}`

which store a value like that: 123234567988,

I need to show this value in the view but in this way: `xxxxxxxx7988`, i mean to hide the first elements, how can i do it, i will appreciate any help as soon as possible?? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create a filter

```
app.filter('cardno', [function () {
    return function (card, args) {
        return (card + '').replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, '*')
    }
}]);
```

then user it like

```
{{ data.cardNumber | cardno}}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QfAP7/)

*Note: The regex is not optimal - need to fix that*

Comment: I create an angularjs file: var homeModule = angular.module('HomeModule', []);

homeModule.filter('cardno', [function () {
    return function (card, args) {
        return (card + '').replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, '*')
    }
}]);

homeModule.filter('card', function () {
    return function (val) {
        return "xxxxxxxx" + (val % 10000);
    };

});

but when i refere the filer in the view {{ data.name | cardno }}  or {{ data.name | card }} i can't see the value i just see {{ data.name | cardno }}, what ma i doing wrong??

Comment: what is the `ng-app` used for the page

Comment: <div ng-app='HomeModule' >

Comment: i dont use any custom filter it works, but if i do a reference to the cutom filter something like that {{ data.accountId | cardno}} all the fields are broken.

Comment: @user3007593 in the fiddle there were few issues... once those are fixed it is fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cS3gC/1/

Comment: This is the situation, i made two simples examples: example1: It example works in fiddle but no in the new page created inside my project: http://jsfiddle.net/QfAP7/6/   , example2: it works in my page for the filter uppercase but no for custom filter, but it doesnt works good en fiddler : http://jsfiddle.net/QfAP7/5/     , i really confused with that. please check them. thank you.

Comment: thanx Guys. i have solved the problem and implemented the functionality using your examples. i had some problems with the main directive but it was solved

Answer (score 0):

Create filter:

```
module.filter('cardNumberFilter', function () {
    return function (val) {
        return "xxxxxxxx"+ (val % 10000);
    };

});
```

Usage:

```
{{ data.cardNumber | cardNumberFilter}}
```

Comment: I create an angularjs file like that:                                                                   var homeModule = angular.module('HomeModule', []);

homeModule.filter('cardno', [function () {
    return function (card, args) {
        return (card + '').replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, '*')
    }
}]);

homeModule.filter('card', function () {
    return function (val) {
        return "xxxxxxxx" + (val % 10000);
    };

});

but when i refere the filer in the view {{ data.name | cardno }}  or {{ data.name | card }} i can't see the value i just see {{ data.name | cardno }}, what ma i doing wrong??

Comment: You probably have not includ ng-app in your HTML

Comment: <div ng-app='HomeModule' >

Comment: i have created una simple page in the project with your code but it doesnt work in my page but the code works in fiddler: check it please: http://jsfiddle.net/dbayonav/9Ky6D/2/  , it is happening the same with my two examples made Arun, check them if it is possible. i dont understand that.

Comment: thanx Guys. i have solved the problem and implemented the functionality using your examples. i had some problems with the main directive but it was solved.